# Error when binding values with dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, ado.net

Created a drop downlist. My Database table contain 2 table

```
Studentregtable :  ID int,FullName varchar,UserName varchar,department varchar.
facultyregtable1 : ID int,FacultyName varchar,DeptName varchar.
```

my aspx code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="147px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

my c# code:

```
public partial class studentfeedbackarea : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            con.Open();

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FacultyName from facultyregtable1 where DeptName=(select department from Studentregtable where UserName=' " + Session["new"].ToString() + " ')", con);
           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           da.Fill(dt);
           con.Close();
           DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
           DropDownList1.DataTextField = "FacultyName";
           DropDownList1.DataValueField = "FacultyName";
           DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

No value shown in drodown list. Why? any error in my code?

Comment: I don't know, *is* there an error? Have you stepped through the code and verified that you're actually getting any data back from your SQL query?

Comment: Query should be `DeptName in (...)` instead of `DeptName=(...)`

Comment: Can you confirm `select department from Studentregtable where UserName=' " + Session["new"].ToString() + " '` this query return only a single value...?

Comment: Run your SQL query in management studio and check is it truly returning some values!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any issues on Code.. but find some issue on Query..

Confirm that your sub Query return only one value...

If it returns more than one value then change  `DeptName =(` to  `DeptName in(` in your query

Also i have noticed a space here -> `' " + Session["new"].ToString() + " '` Remove that space to `'" + Session["new"].ToString() + "'`

**Corrected Query :**

```
select FacultyName from facultyregtable1 where DeptName in(select department from
Studentregtable where UserName='" + Session["new"].ToString() + "')"
```

May be it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in aspx page..............

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" datatextfield="FacultyName" datavaluefield="FacultyName" Height="20px" Width="147px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select FacultyName from facultyregtable1 where DeptName=(select department from Studentregtable where UserName=' " + Session["new"].ToString() + " '
```

In above query I think you are missing quotes near where DeptName='//it should be your sub query with returning one value'